# Question about multiple interviews

Tags: interviewing

I am a software engineer and a fresh graduate from college, so after my graduation trip I start applying to pretty much every job in the area. I heard back from three company's let's call them company A, B, and C.

So today company A calls me back after my first in person interview and tries to schedule an interview, but I already had an interview scheduled with company B.   Thinking I had to provide an excuse to company A I told them that unfortunately I had another interview planned that day while trying to still sound very interested. I know company A wants to hire me but location and job isn't as favorable as company B.  One is more support than development and I want to be in development.

When I told my dad I had told them about another interview he told me it was a major mistake.  I provided them absolutely no details on the other interview apart from the scheduling conflict.  I was wondering how much harm people think I did my mentioning the other interview?

Also company B is a much larger company so I know their process takes much longer.  I Was wondering how much time people thought I could potentially delay company A if they do give me an offer.  I did schedule an interview with company A at a new time.   I know this my final interview at both.  Thanks in advance for other peoples insight.

Comment: Hi neuroh, welcome to The Workplace. It seems like there is more than one question in here. I'd suggest editing it down to focus on the problem you're facing. As a Q&A site, it's easier to vote the best answers to the top when they're more focused. Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only issue I could see in disclosing that you have another interview that is it means company A may have to reschedule things.  There may be some companies that don't like doing this and as a new graduate you could be seen as being picky here.  Granted this is making a mountain out of a molehill but there may exist companies that like that old school style of command and control.

Realistically, I see this as doing the opposite of harm.  This keeps A in the loop that you are interviewing with other places and thus if they are keen on you, to move quickly.

As for delaying A, I'd likely think you may be able to get a few days to mull over an offer though much more than that may be an issue.  Something to consider is what kind of terms would you want to make up for the unfavorable location and role that it is.

Comment: Thank you, I was worried after what my dad said.  Did not want to ruin my chances with company A if I fail my interview at company  B since it still is a good job nonetheless.  I will have to think about what I would want to make up for the differences.  Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

If your strategy is to convince Company A that they are unique and you really want to work there, your dad is right. Specially when you don't have too much experience to show up. Think of the situation of the company, would you rather hire someone that explicitly wanted to work with you vs someone that applies for just "any" job. Which would you choose? On the other hand, the company might value business driven an honest employees - in which case you did the right thing.

Telling them might have other benefits IF they really want to hire you. I.e. it might be easier to negotiate salary and they might act faster.

In the end, these things depends a lot of the managers personal preferences.

Comment: Thank you for  an alternate view point, I do agree I am not in much a position to be selective, however it is true to say I applied everywhere that was hiring I did only pick places that were doing things that interested me. Thanks again for the input I hope they were the type that prefer honesty but I will be more careful.

Comment: Good point that A might be worried to hire someone who would like to leave for B. But you don't have to say "I have interview with B". Instead say like: **“sorry I have something else planned, what other dates are good for you?”**